# Image not showing in vue.js and onsen ui app

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, onsen-ui

I have used the following code to load image in my App which is based on Vue.js and Onsen UI . But they are not showing.

```
  <div class="footer_logo">
    <ul>
      <li class=""><img :src="logo" alt="logo" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I have imported the image using the following code in script

```
import foot1 from 'static/assets/img/footerlogos/1.svg';
export default {
  data() {
      logo: foot1;
  }
```

**Edit**

Project structure

[image]

Comment: The path does not look nice...where is your vue component relative to static folder?

Comment: Vue component is in src folder.I have added the project structure in my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `svg` image can be a problem first change it than check either it
>   works or not. It it's not working follow the following solution.

you have to put all your image files in `assets` folder inside `src` folder not `src/static`

> **Test with this.**
>
> - create assets directory inside src folder ( **make sure it assets not asset or anything else** )
> - add an image ex: logo.jpg

than your code

```
 <div class="footer_logo">
    <ul>
      <li class=""><img :src="logo" alt="logo" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

and finally update your script

```
import foot1 from 'assets/logo.jpg';
export default {
  data() {
      logo: foot1;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If `static` folder is on the root of your project, you should use some `root suffix` like this:

```
import foot1 from '@static/assets/img/footerlogos/1.svg';

export default {
  data() {
      logo: foot1;
}
```

References:

- [Babel Plugin Root Import](https://github.com/entwicklerstube/babel-plugin-root-import)

Comment: Edit your question and, put your folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

Add a relative path like this:

```
import foot1 from '../static/assets/img/footerlogos/1.svg';

export default {
  data() {
      logo: foot1;
}
```